# Destructive backspace in vi

Tags: editor, vi, xterm

How do I make the default backspace/`^H` destructive in vi (not vim)? The cursor jumps to the left as it should, but changes aren't applied until I switch modes. i.e. it deletes the text, but this isn't visible until hitting ESC.

This has been giving me a headache for a while, is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This probably is an issue with the terminal. In any case, keeping the spirit of vi, you should not be using <kbd>backspace</kbd> or <kbd>delete</kbd>. Prefer <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>x</kbd> to achieve the same functionality.